# Membrr: accept donations on top of subscription cost

Tags: subscriptions, membrr

I'm integration Membrr for non-profit organisation.

They want to let people purchase membership and make donation at same time (ex. the user can only purchase membership for $100, or membership ($100) plus donation ($50 or other amount)

Basically this is "pay as much as you want" model, but with minumum set and recurrent billing.

Is there a way in Membrr to add amount to subscription cost?

I know I could use EE Donations module separately, but perhaps there is way to let users pay all they want in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I ended up with creating subscription plans that also include donation. There seems to be no other way around with Membrr.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with Membrr you have to pre-setup your "plans" in Open Gateway and so the recurring cost is "set". As you noted you can run Membrr and Donations both, but those two things have to run separately. The only way I could think you might be able to do it would be set it up so after the form is submitted you use AJAX calls to submit one transaction for Membrr and one for EE Donations. That's less than ideal because you'll end up creating two charges, but I can't think of any other way.